# Docker: How a container persists data without volumes in the container?

Tags: docker, persistence

I'm running the official solr 6.6 container used in a docker-compose environment without any relevant volumes.
If i modify a running solr container the data survives a restart.
I dont see any volumes mounted and it works for a plain solr container:

```
docker run --name solr_test -d -p 8983:8983 -t library/solr:6.6
docker exec -it solr_test /bin/bash -c 'echo woot > /opt/solr/server/solr/testfile'
docker stop solr_test
docker start solr_test
docker exec -it solr_test cat /opt/solr/server/solr/testfile
```

Above example prints 'woot'. I thought that a container doesnt persist any data? Also the [documentation](https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr/blob/master/Docker-FAQ.md) mentions that the solr cores are persisted in the container.
All i found, regarding container persistence is that i need to add volumes on my own like mentioned [here](http://www.computerweekly.com/feature/Docker-storage-how-to-get-persistent-storage-in-Docker).
So i'm confused: do containers store the data changed within the container or not? And how does the solr container achive this behaviour? The only option i see is that i misunderstood peristence in case of docker or the build of the container can set some kind of option to achieve this which i dont know about and didnt see in the solr Dockerfile.

Comment: Could I help you with the answer?

Comment: yep -- many thx, i never used docker commit but knew it existed and mainly thought of containers as a throw away environment for an application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.
The data you create inside a container persist as long as you don't delete the container.

But think containers in some way of throw away mentality. Normally you would want to be able to remove the container with `docker rm` and spawn a new instance including your modified config files. That's why you would need an e.g. named volume here, which survives a container life cycle on your host.

The `Dockerfile`, because you mention it in your question, actually only defines the image. When you call `docker run` you create a container from it. Exactly as defined in the image. A fresh instance without any modifications.

When you call `docker commit` on your container you snapshot it (including the changes you made to the files) and create a new image out of it. They achieve the data persistence this way.
The documentation you referring to explains this in detail.

Comment: good answer. there is to add, that exec does execute a command on a _running_ conatainer only. A start is not a remove, its a "pause" if you will, thus any data is still valid and the container is not removed. When you call start, the very same container is resumed - its not a new container created. Start can only be called on a already created container, not an image - because it never creates and image - that is what run is for, it creates a new container from an image. So start/stop/exec are for existing(created) containers, run creates a new one.

Comment: maybe one more question which i didnt find an answer in a short search: is there some option for docker compose or docker start which forces a container to start from the image on the start - i know i could remove the container, but this would require extra special knowledge on handling compose files. I'm thinking about some apache/php applications which might use a file cache which i would expect to be empty on (re)start as an example.

Comment: look into docker system prune for deletion of networks, volumes and images and docker up --build to rebuild it from your Dockerfile